# How can I make a map function inside lodash .times

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm trying to make a map function for items I get from an API response inside of _.times but it doesn't work, is that even possible, I just want to make a unique id  number for every item and compare every id with the this.state.selected in the className of every item

```
<div className="items">
  {_.times(this.state.items.length, j => ({this.state.items.map(i =><a href="/" id={j} onClick={this.targetValue} className={this.state.selected === j ? "selected" : ""}>{i.name}</a>)}))}
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to just use the index whilst mapping? Although not ideal I'm not too sure what you're trying to achieve unless you can give a better example

Answer (score 0):

Works OK -

```
    render() {
       return (_.times(this.state.items.length, j => this.state.items.map(i => <div>
          <a id={j} href="" className={j === this.state.selected ? "selected": ""}>{i}</a> . 
       </div>)))
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kpcqn7wb/

Note your variable "j" isn't unique - it is the count index of the function call to the function called to _.times, so the id attr will not be unique.

Answer (score 0):

As Win mentioned in the comment, the easiest thing would probably just be to use a normal `_.map()` call over `this.state.items`, and utilize the index of each array item to set the id. Keep in mind that `lodash` nearly always provides two arguments when iterating: in arrays it's `(value, index)` and in objects it's `(value, key)`.

In this case, you could do something like:

```js
<div className="items">
  {_.map(this.state.items, (item, index) =>{
    return(
    <a href="/" id={index} onClick={this.targetValue} className={this.state.selected === index ? "selected" : ""}>{item.name}</a>
    );
  });
  }
</div>
```

Does that help?